# How would I also be able to get the phone number from the contact the user picked?

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

I am able to get the contact name that the user chose but not the phonenumber

In the `onclick` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,            
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_CONTACT);
```

`PICK_CONTACT` is just an int value that equals one its my requestcode

then:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    if (reqCode == PICK_CONTACT) {
        if (resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri contactData = data.getData();

            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                     contactadder.setText(name);


                c.close();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little snippet of my work which perhaps might help you to get the right direction. Android database interaction is poorly documented and hard to find the right way/values. Just reply if you need more help to understand. I removed some business relevant data out, so it will not compile this way. Just for easy post!

```
public static final String[] PROJECTION ={

                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA1,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA2,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA3,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA4,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA5,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA6,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA7,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA8,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA9,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA10,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA11,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA12,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA13,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA14,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA15
        };

private static final int MIMETYPE_COLUMN=0;
private static final int DATA_COLUMN=1;
private static final int DATATYPE_COLUMN=2;

private static final String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ?";

public static ContactWrapper localContact(long contactId){

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,PROJECTION, SELECTION, new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);

    ContactWrapper wrapper = new ContactWrapper(contact);
    if(cursor==null){
        return wrapper;
    }
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){

        String mime=cursor.getString(MIMETYPE_COLUMN);
        if (mime.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
            contact.setU8sDisplayName(cursor.getString(DATA_COLUMN));

        } else if (mime.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
            putPhoneNumber(contact, cursor);

        } else if (mime.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
            putEmail(contact, cursor);

        } else if (mime.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
            putAddress(contact, cursor);

        }else if (mime.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.SipAddress.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
            contact.setU8sSIPAddress(cursor.getString(DATA_COLUMN));
        }else if (mime.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
            wrapper.setImageBinaryString(getContactPhotoBase64(contactId));
        }

    }
    cursor.close();
    return wrapper;
}
private static void putPhoneNumber(ContactWrapper contact,Cursor data){

    switch (data.getInt(DATATYPE_COLUMN)){
        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
            contact.setU8sPhoneHome(data.getString(DATA_COLUMN));
            break;
        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
            contact.setU8sPhoneMobile(data.getString(DATA_COLUMN));
            break;
        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
            contact.setU8sPhoneBusiness(data.getString(DATA_COLUMN));
            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: I just want to be able to get the number and name of the contact the user clicked on, i got the name as you can see but shouldn't there be just one or two lines of code to get the number of that said contact also?  That i could just stick in my if statement @Henning

Comment: But as you can see, there normally is no "the" number a contact can have several. Also you are lucke that the first row contains the name, also this is not for sure. Try to itearate through your resultset and print the coloum of the rows. perhaps you can see what you need